# jQuery mouseover animation with alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is - Writing a page containing a small square,every time user brings the cursor close to the box, the box must move away from the mouse pointer. Finally when the box reaches the corner of the page, it should display a message.
So far, I have animated the box from INITIAL to last position on the screen. How to revert it back to original position, with an alert message??

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var x = $(window).width();
var y = $("#div2").width();
$("#div2").mouseover(function(){

for (var i = y ; i <= x ; i++) {
 $("#div2").animate({
            left: 100 + "px"
        });
 
}
});
});
```

```css
#div2 {

    top: 100px;
    /*left: 100px;*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div2" style="position: relative;"></div><br>
```

Comment: Your javascript is missing closing brackets, I didn't fix that because I don't know if it's part of the problem or not. Please edit them in if it's just a mistake. Also please add relevant css, so that we can run and see what happens.

Comment: @Esko Please note the changes. And provide an approach for the problem

Comment: Please add the css to the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final Solution**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var direction=1;

var x = $(window).width();
var y = $("#div2").width();
var left = 0;
$("#div2").mouseover(function(){



    if(left + y <= x )
    {
        left = left + direction*100;
    $("#div2").animate({


            left: left + "px"
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Moving Back!");
        direction = -1;
        left = left + direction*100;
        $("#div2").animate({

            left: left + "px"

        });
    }
        if(left <= 0)
        {
            direction = 1;
            left = left + direction*100;
            alert("Moving Forward!!");
            $("#div2").animate({

            left: left + "px"

        });
        }





        //$(this).css("left", "0");

});
});
```

Comment: @t1m0n refer my above solution. Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var x = $(window).width();
var y = $("#div2").width();
var left = 0;
$("#div2").mouseover(function(){
left+= 100;
  
  if(left <= x ){
 $("#div2").animate({
            left: left + "px"
        });
  } else {
    alert('Back to original');
    $(this).css('left', '0');
    left = 0;
  }
 
});
});
```

```css
#div2 {

    top: 100px;
    /*left: 100px;*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div2" style="position: relative;"></div><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But, I am able to animate from left to right. The problem is- after checking window size condition, I want it to ANIMATE in a reverse manner. Not directly jump over to left=0; So, want to kinda make left decrement by 100, and animate.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var x = $(window).width();
var y = $("#div2").width();
var left = 0;
$("#div2").mouseover(function(){
left+= 100;
  
  if(left <= x ){
 $("#div2").animate({
            left: left + "px"
        });
  } else {
    alert('Back to original');
    $(this).css('left', '0');
    left=0; //this should be their else it will alert many times...
  }
 
});
});
```

```css
#div2 {

    top: 100px;
    /*left: 100px;*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div2" style="position: relative;"></div><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

i i=529(window width=531) for quick out put initialize i=y then if it reaches end it will be moved to `left:opx`

you said you already made it to move to last and your mistake is you didn't assign i in `left`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var x = $(window).width();
var y = $("#div2").width();

$("#div2").mouseover(function(){

for (var i = 529 ; i <= x ; i++) {
 $("#div2").animate({
            left: i+"px"
        });

 
}
    
        alert("reached");
         $("#div2").animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
    
});
});
```

```css
#div2 {

    top: 100px;
    /*left: 100px;*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div2" style="position: relative;"></div><br>
```

Comment: I figured it out eventually. I took a flag(named direction) and set its value +1 and -1, as and when the box reaches the end of window(On both left and write)

Comment: post your answer i would be helpful in future and mark your solution as solved

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need a loop to animate element to relative position, just use '+=100px' notation. You could also calculate element's next position to prevent if from overflow the window. Check this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var vw = $(window).width();
  var $el = $('#div2');
  var width = $el.width();
  var direction = 1;
  var defaultAmount = 100; // Default travel distance
  var amount = defaultAmount;

  $el.mouseover(function() {
    var changeDir = false;
    // Check if element will be out of range
    if (isOutOfRange() && direction === 1) {
      alert('Will be at the end, will reverse')
      amount = vw - $el.offset().left - width;
      changeDir = true;
    }
    
    if (isAtBeginning() && direction === -1) {
      alert('Will be at the beginning, will reverse')
      amount = $el.offset().left;
      changeDir = true;
    }
    
    $el.animate({
      left: direction === 1 ? '+=' + amount + 'px' : '-='+ amount + 'px'
    });
    
    // Change direction to opposite if ellement is at the edge
    if (changeDir) direction = direction * -1;
    // Return to default 
    amount = defaultAmount;
  });

  function isOutOfRange() {
    return width + amount + $el.offset().left >= vw;
  }
  
  function isAtBeginning(){
    return $el.offset().left - amount <= 0;
  }

});
```

```css
#div2 {
  top: 100px;
  /*left: 100px;*/
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div2" style="position: relative;"></div><br>
```